# Поиск отличий в двух изображениях

Tags: изображения, java, bitmap

Здравствуйте. Есть два bitmap различия между ними минимальны, не более 1 - 2% от числа всех точек. Можно ли как то кроме полного перебора всех точек найти отличия в этих двух bitmap?

Comment: Это, конечно не java, но... http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

И, разумеется, imagemagick перебирает все пиксели.

Comment: А как можно найти все различные пикселы не прочитав их значения? 


Это как доказательство "сортировка, использующая только операции сравнения не может работать быстрее, чем за n * log n".


Можно удостовериться с какой-то вероятностью, что они одинаковые. Или если есть много картинок...

Comment: разбирай изображение по кусочкам. Сравнивай хеши кусочков. Если расходятся - читаем пиксели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что значит "отличия", которые в хотите найти? Просто пометить пиксели, которые различаются? Если да, то ничего не поделаешь, всё равно придётся перебрать все пиксели.

Сравнивая хэши, а потом пиксели мы в худшем случае будем получать по 2 прохода по каждому пикселю. Проще тогда уж пробежаться и за 1 проход XOR-ом сравнивать пиксели или вообще всю картинку целиком.

Comment: Как это 2 прохода? А просто пачку байт никак не сравнить?

Comment: "Сравнивай хеши кусочков" - первый проход. "Если расходятся - сравниваем пиксели." - второй проход. Я и предлагаю "просто пачку байт сравить XOR-ом"

Comment: @AndrewFrolov не уловил эту мысль в ответе. Теперь понятно.